# Changing attributes using JS in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Im using the following code line to change the display attribute in some of my input tags.

```
echo '<style type="text/css"> #Save{display:none;}</style>';
```

So I want to use the same method to define if my input is disabled or if it is a readOnly input.

Im trying to use this, but obviusly is not working at all.

```
echo '<style type="text/css"> #Exist{disabled;}</style>';
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`disabled` is not a CSS property. It's an HTML attribute. If you want to disable an input using PHP you need to echo the disabled attribute onto the element, ie:

```
<input <?php if($disabled){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>>
```

If for some incredibly bizarre reason you **need** to disable an input element using CSS, you could apply `pointer-events: none;` to it, which will prevent user clicks from registering. But this is extremely jury-rigged, not the correct way to disable an input, and incredibly unreliable (users could still 'tab' to the input, for example'). In fact, ignore this section entirely. Do it with HTML.

Just as an addendum, as Endless pointed out, you *can* *target* an element in CSS using `:read-only`, `:disabled`, and other selectors. For example:

```
input:disabled {
    /* some styles */
}
```

The above style will apply only to input elements that are disabled. But actually disabling the input is an HTML task, not a CSS one.

Additionally, while it's not likely to break your code any time soon, it's best practice to begin ID's with lower-case letters, camel-casing if necessary. For example, `#Save` should be `#save`.

Comment: In addition to this i would also want to point out that there is [:read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only) and the [:disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) selector that you can use to change the style based on attributes